# Проблемы с преобразованием строки в целые числа и обратно

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Задача: написать функцию, которая определяет числа в строке и прибавляет 1 к этому числу.

Например: `abc` должен вывести `abc1`, `cde000` должен вывести `cde001`, `xyz0005` должен вывести `xyz0006` и т. д.

***Мой код:***

```py
def increment_string(strng):
    strlist = []
    numlist = []
    x = ''
    y = ''
    for i in strng:
        if i.isdigit() == False:
             strlist.append(i)
             x = ''.join(strlist)
        else:
            numlist.append(i)
            y = ''.join(numlist)
    if len(numlist) == 0:
        return x + '1'
    else:
        y = int(y)
        y +=1
        y = str(y)
        return x + y
```

И, собственно, проблема, которую я не могу решить:

```py
print(increment_string('xyz0005'))
```

выдает мне `xyz6`, а не `xyz0006`.

Comment: И еще: нельзя ничего импортировать

Comment: Поправьте отступы в коде

Comment: Всегда ли число в конце или оно может быть в начале/середине строки ?

Comment: Эмм... ну допустим только в конце

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def increment_string(strng, s=''):
    for a in reversed(strng):
        if a.isdigit():
            if a == '0':
                if s: break
                else: return strng[:-1] + '1'
            else: s = a + s
        elif s: break
        else: return strng + '1'
    s = str(int(s) + 1)
    return strng[:-len(s)] + s
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока в конце цифры, добавляем единичку с переносом. Как только не цифра, прерываем процесс и добавляем 1, если надо

```
def increment_string(strng):
    strng = list(strng)
    rest = 1
    i = len(strng)-1
    while i and strng[i].isdigit() :
        x = int(strng[i]) + rest
        rest,x = divmod(x, 10)
        strng[i] = str(x)
        i -= 1
    if rest :
        strng = strng[0:i+1]+[str(rest)]+strng[i+1:]
    return ''.join(strng)
```

Comment: что значит "с переносом"?

Comment: это значит что х9 даст 0 в конце 0 и 1 переноса. потом ее надо вставить. соответственно 99 даст 100